# I'm not sure how I should translate this: "姉上が戦いを止めて誰もけがをしなかったみたいです"

Tags: meaning

> 姉上が戦いを止めて誰もけがをしなかったみたいです

It SEEMS that the big sister broke up the fight or is it a FACT that she broke up the fight, so "it seems" that no one was injured?

Is "it seems" related to the entire sentence or just to the last part?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is ambiguous and the translation should be done as appropriate for contexts.

That said, SEEMS reading is the more likely. 姉上が戦いをやめたので would favor FACT reading (still ambiguous though).

---

Consider:

- 僕がやめるよう言ったので、彼女は行かなかったみたいです

Obviously 僕が言った cannot be a hearsay, so FACT reading is the only possibility.

- 僕がやめるように言って彼女は行かなかったみたいです

sounds odd. This may suggest ーてーみたい defaults to SEEMS reading.

---

By the way, did you transcribe やめる correctly or was it 止める? In case of the latter, it is とめる.